# lazy evaluation of boost eval_if

Tags: c++, boost, lazy-evaluation

I think i've got a misunderstanding on the lazyness of the eval_if.

The following code is adjusted from the well known member detection mechanism,
where I try to add the functionality that the member should also be convertable to a specific type.

```
template <typename T, typename P = size_t>
struct has_height
{
  private:
    using Yes = char[2];
    using No = char[1];

    struct Fallback
    {
        P height;
    };
    struct Derived : T, Fallback
    {
    };

    template <class U>
    static No &test(decltype(U::height) *);

    template <typename U>
    static Yes &test(U *);

  public:
    static constexpr bool has_member = sizeof(test<Derived>(nullptr)) == sizeof(Yes);

    using value_type = std::integral_constant<bool, has_member>;

    static constexpr bool value = boost::mpl::eval_if<
        value_type,
        std::is_convertible<decltype(T::height), P>,
        boost::mpl::identity<std::false_type>>::type::value;
};

template <typename T, typename P>
const bool has_height<T, P>::value;

template <typename T, typename P>
const bool has_height<T, P>::has_member;
```

However when performing the following:

```
struct TypeA
{
     size_t width;
;

struct TypeB
{
    size_t no_width;
};
EXPECT_TRUE((has_width<TypeA, size_t>::value));
EXPECT_TRUE((has_width<TypeB, size_t>::value));
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/auke/git/base/sdk/src/horus/cmp/prop/reflection/has_width.hpp:49: error: ‘width’ is not a member of refl_test_reflection_types_Test::TestBody()::TypeB’
     static constexpr bool value = boost::mpl::eval_if<
                           ^~~~~
```

I understand what the compiler is saying, just not why. My assumption
here is that since the condition is false (tested) the second parameter (std::is_convertible) is not evaluated.

Any clarity on the matter would be appreciated, a possible fix would be nice too ;)

Auke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you forget `boost::mpl` for a second, and just look at a simplified form of this:

```
eval_if<value_type, A, B>::type::value
```

It should be more clear that `A` and `B` are both evaluated to become the second and third template parameters, which have to be evaluated. So it won't be lazy.

If you want to achieve "lazy" behaviour, you can use template specialisation.

```
template<bool, class T, class P>
struct has_height_helper {
   // `true` case. Evaluate `T::height`
   static constexpr bool value = std::is_convertible<decltype(T::height), P>::value;
}

template<class T, class P>
struct has_height_helper<false, T, P> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
}

// And now use the helper in the class
static constexpr bool value = has_height_helper<has_member, T, P>::value;
```

As template specilisation basically "hides" code depending on what specilisation is used.

Another alternative would be a constexpr function with an `if constexpr` to hide code:

```
template<bool has_member, class T, class P>
constexpr bool has_height_helper() {
    if constexpr (has_member) {
        return std::is_convertible<decltype(T::height), P>::value;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can just bring that up into the struct:

```
template <typename T, typename P = size_t>
struct has_height
{
  private:
    struct Fallback
    {
        P height;
    };
    struct Derived : T, Fallback
    {
    };

    template <class U>
    constexpr static bool test(decltype(U::height) *) {
        return std::is_convertible<decltype(T::height), P>::value;
    }

    template <typename U>
    constexpr static int test(U *) {
        // Basically return any non-bool false so we can tell the difference
        return 0;
    }

  public:
    static constexpr bool has_member = std::is_same<test<Derived>(nullptr), bool>::value;

    using value_type = std::integral_constant<bool, has_member>;

    static constexpr bool value = test<Derived>(nullptr);
};
```